# Redshift: converting timestamp to date in specific time zone

Tags: amazon-redshift

Using psycopg to connect to a Redshift DB I am trying to group by date (in a specific time zone, given at query time). All date_times are stored without time zone (and correspond to UTC timestamps).

I have been trying the following:

```sql
        SELECT DISTINCT DATE(TIME_ZONE(%(time_zone)s, date_time_dim.timestamp)) AS date,
               SUM(meals.sugar_in_g) AS total_sugar
        FROM meals
        INNER JOIN date_time_dim
        ON meals.created_at = date_time_dim.timestamp
        WHERE meals.patient_id=%(patient_id)s
        AND date_time_dim.timestamp >= %(utc_start_date_time)s
        AND date_time_dim.timestamp <= %(utc_end_date_time)s
        GROUP BY date
        ORDER BY date ASC;
```

with the following query dictionary:

- `utc_start_date_time` UTC-converted date time
- `utc_end_date_time`  UTC-converted date time
- `patient_id` an integer
- `time_zone`, a string, ex: 'US/Hawaii'

The goal being to have one entry for each date (in the given time zone).

What I tried gives me:

`function time_zone("unknown", timestamp without time zone) does not exist`

What am I missing ?

Edit: This is the same with `CONVERT_TIME_ZONE`, with and without source time_zone, with and without type casting time_zone to `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function in Redshift to return a timestamp in a different timezone is `TIMEZONE()` not `TIME_ZONE()` - see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/Date_functions_header.html